# Is there a difference between the fourier transform on a distribution and on a function?

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, fourier-transform

I have to calculate the Fourier transform of the following distribution:
$$\langle F_a\mid\phi\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(ax) \phi(x) \, dx, \phi \in \mathcal S (\mathbb{R})$$
Would it be wrong to calculate instead the Fourier transform on:
$$F_a=\cos(ax) \text{?}$$

In both cases, can you show me a complete solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact is that $F_{a}\notin L^{1}({\bf{R}})$, so the integral $\displaystyle\int_{\bf{R}}\cos(ax)e^{-2\pi i\xi\cdot x}dx$ does not exist. Besides that, $F_{a}\notin L^{2}({\bf{R}})$, so the general Fourier transform also does not exist. So we can only speak about the distributional Fourier transform.

For the calculation, note that $\cos(ax)=\dfrac{1}{2}(e^{iax}+e^{-iax})$ and hence for a test function $\varphi\in S({\bf{R}})$, we have
\begin{align*}
\left<\widehat{\cos(ax)},\varphi\right>&=\left<\cos(ax),\widehat{\varphi}\right>\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left<e^{iax},\widehat{\varphi}\right>+\dfrac{1}{2}\left<e^{-iax},\widehat{\varphi}\right>\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\bf{R}}e^{iax}\widehat{\varphi}(x)dx+\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\bf{R}}e^{-iax}\widehat{\varphi}(x)dx\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}(\widehat{\varphi})^{\vee}(a/2\pi)+\dfrac{1}{2}(\widehat{\varphi})^{\vee}(-a/2\pi)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}(\varphi(a/2\pi)+\varphi(-a/2\pi))\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left<\delta_{a/2\pi},\varphi\right>+\left<\delta_{-a/2\pi},\varphi\right>\\
&=\left<\dfrac{1}{2}(\delta_{a/2\pi}+\delta_{-a/2\pi}),\varphi\right>,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\widehat{\cos(ax)}=\dfrac{1}{2}(\delta_{a/2\pi}+\delta_{-a/2\pi})
\end{align*}
in the distributional sense.

Comment: Ok I see. May you show me how to calculate the distributional  Fourier transform?

Comment: I have added the calculation.

Comment: thank you, you are very helpful. May you take a look also at this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650556/limit-and-derivative-of-f-n-f-n-phi-int-0-infty-dx-sin2nx-phix

Comment: I've never seen before the "v" symbol with which you "elevated" the $\phi$ function. What does it stands for?

Comment: is it the antitransform symbol?

Comment: I understand that you used the inversion theorem but I can't understand why you  divided also for $2 \pi$

Comment: Because the formula reads like this: $\widehat{f}(\xi)=\displaystyle\int f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}dx$ and $(\widehat{f})^{\vee}=f$ for sufficiently good functions.

Comment: Perfect. I was confused by the fact that in my book is used a different convention for the fourier transform ($\frac{e^{-ixk}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$

Comment: writing the transform like this I got: $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}(<\delta_a,\phi>+<\delta_{-a}, \phi>$

Comment: Really? But I think the inversion formula from your book should sound a little bit different and the final answer for the question should be the same.

Comment: I'll write you the definitions of transform and antitrasform: $$(\mathcal F \phi)(k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-ikx} \phi(x)$$  $$(\mathcal F^{-1} \phi)(k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ikx} \phi(x)$$

Comment: And the inversion theorem states: $$\phi(x)= \int_{\mathbb{R} } \frac{dk}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{ikx} (\mathcal F \phi)(k)$$

Comment: I guess that your definition is related to the physical meaning of fourier transform as a function that brings a function from the time domain to the frequency domain. And as for the frequency there are these relations that may have something to do: $$\mathcal f=\frac{1}{T}=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$$

Comment: Ah... it may depend on how do you define the Fourier transform for distributions, the answer may vary for some constant, but the Dirac Delta must be there, this is the crucial one.

Comment: but I don't know, the Fourier transform is a total mystery to me. If you have some suggestions/links/articles for me to read you'd be welcome. I really want to figure out something but I'm struggling

Comment: I was reading Loukas Grafakos, Classicla Fourier Analysis, but this is a heavy favour for analysis people, no any physics stuff inside, not sure if this is a book that you will like.

Comment: Yours it's an intimidating book... I'll stick to my physics book!

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about physics so I have no idea for which physics favour book is the right one.