# $f(t)=\frac{\cos(\frac{3}{2}t)}{1+\cos^2(\frac{t}{4})}$ Find period and Fourier expansion

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions

Given the following function:
$$f(t)=\frac{\cos(\frac{3}{2}t)}{1+\cos^2(\frac{t}{4})}$$
Find period and Fourier expansion.

---

I think the period is $T=4 \pi$, observing the functions.

As for the Fourier expansion I have no clue on how to proceed. I know that
$$f(t)= \pi a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \cos(\frac{kt}{2})$$
$$a_k=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi} dt f(t)\cos(kt/2)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-2\pi}^{2\pi} dt \frac{\cos(\frac{3}{2}t) \cos(kt/2)}{1+\cos^2(\frac{t}{4})}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} dt \frac{\cos(\frac{3}{2}t) \cos(kt/2)}{1+\cos^2(\frac{t}{4})}$$
Even with the residue theorem the integral looks really bad since there is that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$... Do I really have to compute this thing?

Comment: Your function is even. You need only the cosine part of Fourier expansion.

Comment: @YuriyS Thank you, I've tried to edit my question taking your suggestion, so I have to compute this integral?

Comment: @Yuriy I've tried to compute it with wolfram and the computation timed out... Maybe my integral is still wrong

Comment: The sum now needs to start with $k=1$, I believe. The functions under the integral are even so you should multiply by $2$ and set the lower limit to $0$. Finally, set $ t/4$ as the new variable. Then your integrals reduce to something well known. If you can't look them up and need to derive yourself, good luck

Comment: In all seriousness, residues are probably the best way. Another way is deriving a recurrence relation, using trigonometric formulas

Comment: Or maybe use $t/2$ as the new variable, and transform $$1+\cos^2( t/4 )= 3/2+1/2 \cos (t/2)$$

Comment: @YuriyS tomorrow I'll maybe try to solve the integral... So this is the only way to get a fourier expansion? No tricks or shortcuts?

Comment: If there had been a better way in general, we would have been taught it...

Comment: In mathematics, @YuriyS, your teachers may not always have known the best way.

Comment: @Lubin I would love to have a map and a compass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way through this.
$$\begin{align}f(t)&=\frac{4\cos\left(3\frac t2\right)}{4+4\cos^2\left(\frac t4\right)}=\frac{4\cos\left(3\frac t2\right)}{4+\left(e^{i\frac t4}+e^{-i\frac t4}\right)^2}\label{a}\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{4\cos\left(3\frac t2\right)}{e^{-i\frac t2}\left(e^{it}+6e^{i\frac t2}+1\right)}=\frac{4\cos\left(3\frac t2\right)}{z^{-1}\left(z^2+6z+1\right)}\label{b}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{4\cos\left(3\frac t2\right)}{z^{-1}\left(z+\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^2\right)\left(z+\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{-2}\right)}\label{c}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac{4\cos\left(3\frac t2\right)}{4\sqrt2z^{-1}}\left(\frac1{z+\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{-2}}-\frac1{z+\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^2}\right)\label{d}\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{\cos\left(3\frac t2\right)}{\sqrt2}\left(\frac1{1+\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{-2}z^{-1}}-\frac z{\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^2\left(1+\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{-2}z\right)}\right)\label{e}\tag{5}\\
&=\frac{\cos\left(3\frac t2\right)}{\sqrt2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kz^{-k}}{\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{2k}}-\frac z{\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kz^k}{\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{2k}}\right)\label{f}\tag{6}\\
&=\frac{\cos\left(3\frac t2\right)}{\sqrt2}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kz^{-k}}{\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{2k}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kz^k}{\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{2k}}\right)\label{g}\tag{7}\\
&=\frac{\cos\left(3\frac t2\right)}{\sqrt2}\left(1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\cos\left(k\frac t2\right)}{\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{2k}}\right)\label{h}\tag{8}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\cos\left(3\frac t2\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{2k}}\left(\cos\left((k+3)\frac t2\right)+\cos\left((k-3)\frac t2\right)\right)\right)\label{i}\tag{9}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^6}\left(-1+6\cos\left(\frac t2\right)-34\cos\left(2\frac t2\right)\right)\\
&\quad-99\sqrt2\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^{2k}}\cos\left(k\frac t2\right)\label{j}\tag{10}\end{align}$$
$(\ref{a})$ Convert $\cos\left(\frac t4\right)$ to complex exponential
$(\ref{b})$ Square out, substitute $z=\exp\left(i\frac t2\right)$ and isolate classic polynomial in $z$
$(\ref{c})$ Factor polynomial from equation $(\ref{b})$
$(\ref{d})$ Partial fractions decomposition
$(\ref{e})$ Ready for geometric series expansion!
$(\ref{f})$ Geometric series expansion away SIR!
$(\ref{g})$ Pull out $k=0$ term of $z^{-k}$ sum and multiply $z^k$ sum by its prefactor
$(\ref{h})$ Consolidate $z^{-k}+z^k=\exp(-ikt/2)+\exp(ikt/2)=2\cos(kt/2)$
$(\ref{i})$ Multiply through by $\cos(3t/2)$ and use $2\cos\alpha\cos\beta=\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)$ to make it look like a Fourier series
$(\ref{j})$ Clean up Fourier series a little

The same technique may be used IIRC to establish for the radius of a Kepler orbit
$$r=\frac{a\left(1-e^2\right)}{1+e\cos\theta}=a\sqrt{1-e^2}\left(1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-e^2}}e\right)^k}\cos(k\theta)\right)$$
**EDIT**: Just to illustrate the disconnect between the line of the original question that asked for
$$f(t)=a_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k\cos\left(\frac{kt}2\right)$$
And the next line that computed the coefficients of
$$\bar f(t)=\bar a_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\bar a_k\cos\left(kt\right)+\bar b_k\sin\left(kt\right)\right)$$
We present a Matlab program that plots the original function on $[0,2\pi]$ along with the Fourier cosine series that is the periodic extension of $\bar f$ as an even function and the total Fourier series for $\bar f$, Gibbs phenomenon and all.

```
% fourier.m

clear all;
close all;
g = @(t) cos(3/2*t)./(1+cos(t/4).^2);
t= linspace(0,2*pi,300);
nf = 100;
for k = 1:nf,
    h = @(t) g(t).*cos(k*t);
    a(k) = integral(h,0,2*pi)/pi;
    j = @(t) g(t).*sin(k*t);
    b(k) = integral(j,0,2*pi)/pi;
end
a0 = integral(g,0,2*pi)/(2*pi);
f = g(t);
for n = 1:length(t),
    e(n)= a0+cos([1:nf]*t(n))*a';
    d(n) = e(n)+sin([1:nf]*t(n))*b';
end
plot(t,f,'k-',t,e,'b-',t,d,'r-');
title('Fourier Series for Problem');
xlabel('t');
ylabel('y');
legend('f(t)','Cosine series','Total series','Location','Best');
```

[image: Effects of periodic extension]

Comment: This looks good, though I haven’t had the courage to check every step. You should expand $\cos\frac{3t}2$ as a polynomial in $cos\frac t2$, however.

Comment: @Lubin Actually, if you look at step $(9)$ above, $\cos\frac{3t}2$ was the most convenient form for it. Polynomials in $\exp(it/2)$ are easy to convert to Fourier series; polynomials in $\cos\frac t2$ are more awkward.

Comment: @user5713492 I'm impressed...! There's no way I could think up such a calculation. It was an exercise proposed during a test at my university, I wonder how many students nailed it

Comment: @user5713492 Last question! In (5) did you suppose that $|z|<(1+\sqrt2)^2$?

Comment: $|z|=\left|\exp\left(i\frac t2\right)\right|=\left|\cos\left(\frac t2\right)+i\sin\left(\frac t2\right)\right|=\sqrt{\cos^2\left(\frac t2\right)+\sin^2\left(\frac t2\right)}=1$

Comment: @user5713492 beautiful graph by the way

Answer (score 2):

I will still show the evaluation of the integrals, since it's not always possible to use tricks, sometimes we need the general methods as well. (For what it's worth, in this case the integrals are very simple).

**Edited** because the period of the function is $4 \pi$ the correct expression should be:

$$a_k=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}  \frac{\cos(\frac{3}{2}t) \cos \left( \frac{kt}{2} \right)}{1+\cos^2(\frac{t}{4})}dt=\frac{4}{\pi }\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos(3x) \cos(kx)}{3+\cos x}dx=$$

Now the residue theorem is the most convenient way here, in my opinion, so we transform the integral the following way:

$$=\frac{2}{\pi } \Re \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos(3x) e^{ikx}}{3+\cos x}dx=\frac{2}{\pi } \Re \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\left(e^{3ix}+e^{-3ix} \right) e^{ikx}}{6+e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}dx=$$

Setting $z=e^{ix}$ and choosing the unit circle as the contour, we have:

$$=\frac{2}{\pi } \Re \left( -i \oint \frac{\left(z^3+z^{-3} \right) z^{k-1}}{6+z+z^{-1}}dz \right)=\frac{2}{\pi } \Re \left( -i \oint \frac{\left(z^6+1 \right) z^{k-3}}{6z+z^2+1}dz \right)=$$

We assume $k>2$, the cases $k=0,1,2$ can be dealt with separately (there will be an additional pole at $z=0$ of order $1,2,3$). For other cases, we need to consider only the poles coming from the denominator:

$$z^2+6z+1=0$$

$$z= \pm 2 \sqrt{2}-3$$

Of the roots, only one lies inside the unit circle ($z= 2 \sqrt{2}-3$), so we only need to compute one residue:

$$=\frac{2}{\pi } \Re \left( 2 \pi \frac{\left((2 \sqrt{2}-3)^6+1 \right) (2 \sqrt{2}-3)^{k-3}}{2 \sqrt{2}-3+2 \sqrt{2}+3} \right)=\frac{(2 \sqrt{2}-3)^{k-3}+(2 \sqrt{2}-3)^{k+3}}{\sqrt{2}}    $$

So, finally, for $k>2$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have:

> $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}  \frac{\cos(\frac{3}{2}t) \cos \left( \frac{kt}{2} \right)}{1+\cos^2(\frac{t}{4})}dt=\frac{(2 \sqrt{2}-3)^{k-3}+(2 \sqrt{2}-3)^{k+3}}{\sqrt{2}} $$

Note that:

$$2 \sqrt{2}-3=\frac{1-\sqrt{2}}{1+\sqrt{2}}=-\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{2})^2}$$

Comment: I have done the same thing with some difficulties in the initial calculations (your initial substitution is really smart!). I didn't find the integrals so simple!

Comment: Anyway thank you for the help in the comments & in this well written answer

Comment: The problem with this is that you are starting with a function with period $4\pi$ and making the periodic extension of the function in the domain $\left(0,2\pi\right)$. But then why did the Fourier coefficients decrease exponentially, shouldn't they be $O\left(1/k\right)$ because the function they represent has a discontinuity at $t=0$? The answer is that they are, but only the Fourier sine coefficients! So it will be necessary to find $$b_k=\frac1{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}[\dots]\sin(kt)dt$$ as well before you get a series that matches the function. Try plotting what you have so far.

Comment: @user5713492 thank you for your observation! It seems that in the end your answer is the most complete solution to my problem and certainly the next time I'll see something similar to this problem I'll try to use your method. Yuriy still I like your integral. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @Gitana, I see the problem now. Your formula for the Fourier coefficients is not correct in this case, it should have been $\cos \frac{kt}{2}$ in the integral

Comment: @user5713492, thank you for the comment. I have fixed my answer now

Comment: @Yuriy right! I corrected my question. The residue is now much better. Later I'll try to calculate also $b_k$. I'm happy that the residue method works.

Comment: @Gitana, now that I fixed the integral, you don't need $b_k$, in other words, $b_k$ is the imaginary part of the contour integral, which as you can see, is zero. Just make sure that your series fit with the answer of user5713492

Comment: @Yuriy ahhh so also user's matlab code is wrong! Since it relies on my wrong formula... now that $f(t)$ and $sin(kt/2)$ share the same period $b_k$ is the integral of a odd function, id est zero... is it right?

Comment: @Gitana, no, it's not wrong, since they get the original function. See the series they obtained, which only contains cosines with the correct period. The sines appear if we use incorrect period

Comment: @Yuriy yes I mean that they use the wrong formula

Comment: @Gitana, if the formula works, it can't be wrong. They used it specifically to show that I computed thr wrong integral. Anyway, to avoid confusion it's better to do everything exactly by definition

Comment: I kind of wanted to see what $b_k$ would have looked like but (+1) anyway